# SAS hash objects: multidata merge

Tags: hash, sas

I'm new to hash objects, but I'd like to learn more about them. I'm trying to find ways to substitute all possible proc sql and regular merges with hash whenever possible. While playing around with SASHELP datasets, I ran into the following issue:

Let's say I have a dataset of 10 unique observations (car manufacturer) and I want to match it up with another table that contains various models of these cars, so the car make repeats in that table. The other important aspect to note is that not all car makes are present in the table I'm looking up, but I still would like to retain those in my table.

Consider the code below:

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table x as select distinct make
    from sashelp.cars;
quit;

data x;
    set x (obs = 10);
    if make = "GMC" then make = "XYZ";
run;


data hx (drop = rc);

if 0 then set sashelp.cars(keep = make model);
if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash hhh(dataset: 'sashelp.cars(keep = make model)', multidata:'y');
    hhh.DefineKey('make');
    hhh.DefineData('model');
    hhh.DefineDone();
end;

set x;
rc = hhh.find();
do while(rc = 0);
    output;
    rc = hhh.find_next();
end;

if rc ne 0 then do;
    call missing(model);
    output;
end;

run;
```

If all makes in table X were also in table cars, then removing `output` command after `call missing(model)` would do exactly what I want. But I also want to make sure that make "XYZ" will remain in the table.

The existing code, however, produces a blank after it find all matching models, like so:

```
make model
==========
Acura MDX
Acura RSX Type S 2dr
Acura TSX 4dr
... (skipping a few rows)
Acura NSX coupe 2dr manual S
Acura 
Audi A4 1.8T 4dr
```

As you can see, in the above table, there is a missing model in the second to last row. This pattern appears in the end of every make.

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be highly appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer: you need to consider this section.

```
rc = hhh.find();
do while(rc = 0);
    output;
    rc = hhh.find_next();
end;

if rc ne 0 then do;
    call missing(model);
    output;
end;
```

What's happening here is you are repeatedly trying to find next, fine, until you fail.  Okay.  Now you're in `rc ne 0` condition, though, even though you really mean that last step to only be used if you didn't even find one.

You can handle this a couple of ways.  You can do this:

```
rc = hhh.find();
if rc ne 0 then do;
  call missing(model);
  output;
end;
else
do while(rc = 0);
    output;
    rc = hhh.find_next();
end;
```

Or, you can add a counter to the do while loop, and then execute the call missing/output if that counter stores a 0.  The above is probably easier.

Further, you probably should consider whether a hash is the right solution for this problem.  While it is possible to solve this with multidata hashes, keyed set is usually more efficient for something like this, and much easier to code.

Comment: Thanks Joe, really appreciate your answer. You are right, hash might not be the right solution here, I suppose I was just interested to find out how can hash be used to substitute such operations.

Comment: Hash object is definitely interesting to play with, and sometimes it is the better option of course.  If you get the SAS-L mailing list, you will often see interesting discussions on the best ways to do different things, including Paul Dorfman (who was one of the original Hashers).